# Can't find this character in the dictionary

Tags: orthography, kana

I have been looking for the meaning of this

[image]

I can't seem to find its meaning. And I see it being used a lot.
Is it even a kanji, or is it just an expression?

Answer (score 7):

This is the hiragana そ. You may be confused because of the font.

Comment: FWIW, there are two ways of writing the character: either with one stroke, or two strokes. The one-stroke way is what is taught to schoolchildren these days, and the one you're most likely to run across in printed text. The question has [the two-stroke variant.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Hiragana_so.png) (Me? I find the two-stroke one to be easier to handwrite.)