# What is the regular kana text of the image?

Tags: meaning, kana

What is the regular kana text of the image ?
the context:https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=66035643

[image: What is regular kana of the image ?]

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41260/cant-find-this-character-in-the-dictionary?

Comment: @Leebo You're right, but I still can't understand that meaning,should I  edit this question only ? or post a new question in this website only?

Comment: If you have questions about the meaning, try to research it, then edit the question with a summary of your best ideas on it. Then people can address that. Pure translation requests aren't answered here.

Comment: To add, the image straight up shows two Hiragana (i.e. regular Kana). So the image already is your answer. If you want to get an idea of their pronunciation search for 'Hiragana chart' and you should find any number of websites where you can look them up. No worries, you're not up against a wall of 4000 Kanji here, just a small table with some 70 different symbols - two of which are the ones you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In meaning,

> 「もそっ」＝「もそ」＝「もそもそ」＝「もぞもぞ」

These are the variants of an onomatopoeia used to describe the fidgeting and/or restless movement of a human/animal body or body part.

Needless to say, this has nothing to do with 「そもそも」, which means "in the first place".