# What is this Kanji? I can’t find it anywhere?

Tags: meaning, kanji, hiragana, handwriting, japanese-to-english

[image]

I’ve been searching radicals on Jisho and other places but I can’t find a kanji to match this one.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41260/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53835/5010

Comment: Can you give more context? Where you found it, surrounding text, etc.

Answer (score 14):

That’s likely not a kanji, but rather a hiragana そ (*so*) in its split/handwritten form (like on the right here):

[image]

Comment: Only now do I see that the top half of the handwritten そ is the katakana ソ!

Comment: @muru: hiragana **そ** ≅ katakana **ソ** + hiragana **て**.  It's almost a "sleeve".  ^_^

Comment: Where are the two images from?